# Trying to persist my react state and getting infinite loop on render

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

When attempting to use localStorage to persist my react state, I am getting infinite re-renders and I can see in dev tools that the state is constantly being filled then unfilled.

I understand that it is my usage of useEffect that can be causing this and maybe my condition for filling my Map Object with the stored state.

setting the state item works without issue.

retrieving it does not.

Any help greatly appreciated.

my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.myCartState ? setCart(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.myCartState))) 
    :
    setCart(new Map())
  }) 

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.myCartState = JSON.stringify(Array.from(cart.entries()));
},[cart])
```

and here is my initialState of the cart:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(new Map())
```

Comment: Try giving the first effect an empty dependency array so it doesn't run every render `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`.

Comment: Did you try to give ' [] 'as second argument of first useEffect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining `useEffect` without a [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) will cause it to be called on every render. In your `useEffect` you are setting state, which triggers a render. This causes an infinite loop.

If you want that first effect to only run on component mount, pass it an empty dependency array. Something like this may resolve the issue:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.getItem('myCartState') ? setCart(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCartState')))) 
    :
    setCart(new Map())
, []);
```

For more information, I recommend reading the docs on [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), which covers this in a lot more detail.

In addition to that, the usage of `localStorage` appears to be incorrect. You'll want to use [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) and [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) when getting/storing data into `localStorage`.

Comment: giving it the empty array does not persist the state on reload

Comment: That's a separate issue and it appears to be how you're calling `localStorage`. You're probably looking for `localStorage.getItem('myCartState')`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Similarly, when you go to set the cart state, you'll want to use `localStorage.setItem('myCartState',  JSON.stringify(Array.from(cart.entries())));`

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data you are retrieving and storing in `localStorage.myCartState` is setting its value `true` in the ternary operation inside your first `useEffect` hook, where you are using a state update function `setCart`, which updates state again causing a re-render, loading the first `useEffect` hook again where the condition is again true and state changes, and so on.

If you are using the first hook only once in your program run, you can pass an empty list `[]` as additional parameter of the hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.myCartState ? setCart(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.myCartState))) 
    :
    setCart(new Map())
  }, [])
```

else you might want to consider changing your ternary operation or maybe carry a different state/variable to cause the hook to trigger instead of triggering during every render.

Cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a momemt to explain the WHY and not only to answer how to solve this.

useEffect hook takes 2 arguments. A callback and a dependency array where the array determinates when the callback would be executed  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

No take a look at the code behind

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.myCartState ? setCart(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.myCartState))) 
    :
    setCart(new Map())
  })
```

here you are passing your callback a no dependency array, which means "run the callback each time the component is render"

and at the bottom of the callback you are doing `setCart(new Map())` which is and state update.
Updating a state is one of the causes of a re-render https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html  and a Re-render is the cause of triggering useEffect callback and useEffect Callback is updating an state... and so on

So, basically your are creating an infinite loop of state updating, rendering and triggering the callback.

How to solve

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.myCartState ? setCart(new Map(JSON.parse(localStorage.myCartState))) 
    :
    setCart(new Map())
  })
```

Update your useEffect to take an empty array to limit the triggers to the first render and be aware that each time your a having a infinite re-render loop the cause might be

1. Not passing a dep array
2. Updating a state that is referenced in the dep array